# Windows batch file programming (.bat)

Tags: batch-file

How to delete all disconnected users in task manager, using batch (`.bat`) file only?

I have tried this below mentioned code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set Server=%1371870%
REM set 'test' to an empty string instead of ECHO to run it for real:
set test=ECHO
REM *** Logoff all disconnected sessions:
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('query session /server:"%Server%" ^| find /i "disc"') do (
  %test% logoff /server:"%Server%" "%%a" /v
)
REM *** Logoff all idle sessions:
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('query session /server:"%Server%" ^| find /i "idle"') do (
  %test% logoff /server:"%Server%" "%%a" /v
)
```

Comment: I am certainly sure that the `%` around `1371870` should be deleted... And you should as well specify your question... As currently written it is hard to tell what exactly you are asking.

Comment: PLEASE provide a more specific question title! the one you used is completely useless!

Comment: Does it give any errors? Any output?  How is it different than what you intended when you wrote this script? (In fact, you don't _actually_ say it doesn't work!). Debug tips: Remove the `echo off` so you can see the commands as they run. In particular, as @geisterfurz007 says, work out what you meant `%371870% to do (you _can_ create environment variables with all-numeric names, but you really shouldn't).